# What's new in A Game of Thrones 2nd Edition?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I recently acquired the 2nd Edition of A Game of Thrones: The Board Game. I've played the older edition for years.

I'm having people over to play the new version later today, many of whom are familiar with the old version, but I haven't exhaustively read the new rules yet. I noticed in the quick reference sheet that there are minor (but important!) rules differences, such as how the Star Raid order works.

What rules changes have there been since the first edition and its expansions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, according to [this post at BGG](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/article/7649113#7649113), the rules changes are

- Unit counts - each house has 5 knights and 2 siege engines, instead
  of 4 knights and 3 siege engines.
- Setup changed to include various neutral forces tokens.
- Wildling Attack cards added.
- Garrison token of 2 for each house's starting position.
- Play to 7 castles regardless of player count.
- Wildling threat of 12 triggers an attack.
- Messenger raven allows you to look at the top card in the Wildling Attack deck (OR replace an order).
- Raiding a Consolidate Power order makes the target lose a power token (in addition to the raiding house gaining a token).
- When playing your 7th house card, you get the other 6 cards back, but not that last one played.
- Special raid order can remove a defense order, but NOT 2 orders.
- Special consolidate power order can muster units OR gain power tokens as usual.
- 4 player game is played without Tyrell (instead of without Greyjoy).
- Tides of battle cards.

Comment: Played the game a number of times and never knew you could use the raven to look at the wildling deck...

Comment: Can the Consolidate Power order be placed on a land territory without a Power Icon to get 1 Power Token? Or must it be placed on a territory with a crown?

Comment: @JohnPeyton yes, either on a land territory or in a port. But you only collect power tokens for the latter if your port is not blockaded (no enemy ships in the connected sea area).

Answer (score 2):

I know, this answer comes late, but for the sake of completeness, I will add it anyway.

Sveinns answer mentions the biggest and most important changes, but there were three nitpicks he missed.

- If Tyrell kills a single attacking or defending Footman, it does not immediately end combat in favour of Tyrell. Combat strength is still calculated and the one with higher combat strength wins.
- If House Card abilities are supposed to be resolved at the same time, in second edition the order on the Iron Throne track decides, not the order on the Fiefdom track.
- A tie in Victory Track position after ten rounds is broken by the number of controlled Strongholds first, then Supply Track, then available Power Tokens, then Iron Throne Track position. (1st edition didn't care about the number of Strongholds)